# Writing a linux bash script to add a user to a group in eDirectory

Tags: bash, ldap, edirectory

I want to write a shell script to bulk add users to a group in eDirectory. The trouble is, I'm not sure where to begin regarding LDAP calls and whatnot for this task. Can anyone point me to a helpful resource or demonstrate a method for accomplishing this task?

Using straight-up LDAP would be fine, but I imagine that there must exist faster utilities/constructs that can be used in shell.

NetIQ's LDAPConfig or NDSConfig utilities seemed promising, but I don't see anything about adding a user to a group in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I don't have to code a solution to this. Instead of selecting each item and adding them to a group, there's a tool buried deep inside iManager that allows you to select all users matching a set of conditions and add them to a group.